# Calling Constructor of inheriting class C# reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, constructor

I am using reflection to get my assembly loaded.

Below is my code of assembly which will be loaded by reflection:

```
using BaseDll;

namespace CustomLibrary
{
    public class CustomClass : BaseClassofDll
    {
        // Creating all constructors as of base class
        public CustomClass() : base() { }
        public CustomClass(string s1, string s2) : base(s1,s2) { }
        public CustomClass(string s1, string s2, object obj) : base(s1, s2, obj) { }

        public override void Method1() { }
        public override void Method2() { }
    }
}
```

Reflection code :

```
namespace MyLibrary
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public void CreateAssemblyClass()
        {
            string dllPath = "C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Temp\CustomLibrary.dll"
            Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(dllPath);
            // asm is loaded with correct dll

            Type t = asm.GetType("CustomLibrary.CustomClass");
            // t is initialized with correct class

            object[] constructorParameters = new object[2];
            constructorParameters[0] = "123";   // First parameter.
            constructorParameters[1] = "456";   // Second parameter.

            dynamic result = Activator.CreateInstance(t, constructorParameters);
            // Get Exception here : Constructor on type 'CustomLibrary.CustomClass' not found."

            t.GetConstructors();
            // This gives only single constructor of type ctor()
            // My constructor with 2 or 3 parameters is not found. 

            ConstructorInfo ctor = t.GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(string),typeof(string) });
            // This gives null
        }
    }
}
```

How to create insatnce of CustomClass using parameterized constructor. This is necesaary as I am overriding 2 methods in my CustomClass and hence I want to use CustomClass and not BaseClassofDll.

Edit:
As many of you are asking to share code of BaseClassofDll, let me tell you BaseDll is a 3rd party dll. And while peeking into its definition , it is like below:

```
public class BaseClassofDll
{
    public BaseClassofDll();
    public BaseClassofDll(string s1);
    public BaseClassofDll(object obj, string s1);
    public BaseClassofDll(string s1, string s2);
    public BaseClassofDll(object obj, string s1, string s2);

    /*****Other methods ***/
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the code of the base class (with the exact visibility modifiers you have)? Where does the base class reside? Second option: are you sure you're loading the correct DLL (not an old version where the class really has only 1 constructor)?

Comment: Looks like good to me. Your code should be work. Would you share BaseClassOfDll too ?

Comment: @felix-b I have edited my question

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. I personally suspect the base class is irrelevant here. It sounds like you may be using an old version of your DLL, or something like that. (One simple way of avoiding that for test purposes is to use a type within the same assembly. If that works, move on to trying one in a `LoadFrom`-loaded assembly.)

Comment: @Jon Skeet we asked to provide the code of the base class because we ran out of ideas. My bet is an old version of the DLL, too. Don't see any other reason for such a behavior.

Comment: @Vandita Use a disassembly tool (e.g. Telerik JustDecompile available at https://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx), open DLL you are trying to load, and re-check what code actually resides there. Most likely, CustomClass you'll find there differs from the example you posted.

Comment: agree with @felix-b

Answer (score 0):

use asm.CreateInstance("CustomLibrary.CustomClass");
i think i should work.
 Pass your parameters.I have hard coded it.

Comment: Your code is working for me. However I am assigning properties after creating instance. So this is not correct solution. I want to instantiate class using my parameterized constructor

Answer (score 0):

The **GetConstructors** function without arguments will only show public, non static constructors. Please verify that your actual implementation matches theses conditions:

```
Default flags: BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance
```

[MSDN: Type.GetConstructors Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e687hf0d(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: All 3 constructors in the question are public instance constructors. A call to GetConstructors() of the Type perfectly returns all 3 of them. There is something else that's getting in the way.

Comment: In your code you write the comment: This gives only single constructor of type ctor()

Comment: @Chrillie I'm not the OP :) but the code in the question works for me as it is. Something else is the problem (I bet that OP is trying to load an old version of the DLL, but if I'm wrong, I wonder maybe we're facing an interesting problem here)

Comment: @felix-b Ah, ok :) I agree with you, I think the example code is not exactly what is actually running on his side.